# Virtualenv in Mac OSX -bash: command not found issue

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion, virtualenv, pip, homebrew

I'm having a really hard time trying to use virtualenv on Mac OSX Mountain Lion.

I installed XCode, python2.7 with Homebrew and virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper using sudo PIP.

I've added usr/local/share/python to my $PATH and also followed the advice given on this site:

http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-virtualenv-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion-10.8/

and edited my ~/bashrc accordingly.

But when I run virtualenv ENV I get:

-bash: virtualenv: command not found

I've been through steps outlined in a lot of similar questions on SO but none of them have worked so far.  I'd be massively grateful for some help and advice.

Comment: Resoved it thanks.  Despite adding usr/local/share/python to my $PATH and restarting finder when I did this post and it didn't work first time, doing it again has got it working.  Woo hoo!

Comment: Please close the question then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why "virtualenv: command not found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692240/why-virtualenv-command-not-found)