# Virtualenv installation on OS X

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install `virtualenv` on my Mac running OS X Mavericks. To install `virtualenv`, I used `pip`

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Now when I try to use it, I get the message saying
`-bash: virtualenv: command not found`

Also, an attempt to reinstall gets me this:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

My path and python path variable in the file `~/.bash_profile` are set to:

```
export PATH = /usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: @Avinash what's the point of recommending a Linux Cubans when op clearly stated they were on OSX?

Comment: give version details of OS X, pip and virtualenv

Comment: and also check [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96325/cant-create-virtualenv)

Comment: OS X Maverics (10.9.4), pip is the latest stable release and virtualenv is also the latest release available on pip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To re-install `virtualenv` you will first have to uninstall the current version through `pip` by using the command:

`$ pip uninstall virtualenv`

From here, [it is not all too important](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) that `virtualenv` is installed under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. For example, doing a quick `$ which virtualenv` shows me that I have mine under:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/virtualenv`

and I just use `$ virtualenv --python=python_version environment_name` to select which python version the environment runs.

So, after uninstalling run `$ pip install virtualenv` again and then check where it is installed using `$ which virtualenv`

After that you should just be able to create and run your virtual environments straight away using:

Create:

`$ virtualenv evnironment_name`

Run:

`$ source ./environment_name/bin/activate`

or `cd` to the environment directory first and then `$ source bin/activate`

To exit the environment just run `$ deactivate`

I hope this helped!

Comment: Uninstalling & reinstalling results in the same issue as mentioned in the question - command not found.

Comment: @Guarav Just to double check, have you tried the re-install using sudo? If that and a [relaunch of finder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168754/virtualenv-in-mac-osx-bash-command-not-found-issue)/restart of your machine doesn't work I'm out of my depth :( I hope someone else has the correct answer you need

Comment: Yep, tried installing sudo and restarted the mac. :(