# Why "virtualenv: command not found"?

Tags: python, virtualenv

It's telling me that the virtualenv command not found, doesn't anyone know what the problem might be?

```
Brendans-MacBook-Pro:TestProject brendan.whiting$ python --version
Python 3.5.0
Brendans-MacBook-Pro:TestProject brendan.whiting$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Users/brendan.whiting/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages
Brendans-MacBook-Pro:TestProject brendan.whiting$ virtualenv venv
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
Brendans-MacBook-Pro:TestProject brendan.whiting$
```

Comment: possible dublicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453793/how-to-add-virtualenv-to-path

Comment: `virtualenv` is not in your PATH is the reason. *Why* that is, I do not know.

Comment: This answer maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276329/cant-load-python-modules-installed-via-pip-from-site-packages-directory

Answer (score 1):

If you use mac os x then the path may not be included in PYTHONPATH variable, so you need to append it with the actual path of  modules.